# Azure IoT Edge x86 Linux Support

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but is anyone aware of Azure IoT Edge support for Linux x86 processors? I think the answer is no because I don't see this option listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/support#operating-systems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct. Azure IoT Edge does not support Linux x86 and there are no imminent plans to do so.